# Реализовать горизонтальный скроллинг только к ближайшему элементу

Tags: react-native

Я использую FlatList для горизонтального скролла. Работает как ожидается. Могу скролить как к ближайшему элементу, так и сразу к последнему. Зависит от приложенной к экрану силы. Но мне нужно, чтобы при любом усилии скролл осуществлялся только к ближайшему элементу. Это можно реализовать стандартным FlatList или нужно использовать другие решения?

Answer (score 1):

Нашел в доке, что FlatList имеет свойство disableIntervalMomentum. По умолчанию - false. Установка в true, решило мою проблему